# Getting "Full authentication is required to access this resource" when using JWT grant

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I have successfully executed an example code from Github and in sample Java, I am able to fetch envelopes by calling

```
OAuthToken accessToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(INTEGRATOR_KEY, USER_ID, scopes, privateKeyBytes, 3600);apiClient.setAccessToken(accessToken.getAccessToken(), accessToken.getExpiresIn());
UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.getUserInfo(accessToken.getAccessToken());
```

it is working fine. But when I try to replicate in Springboot by importing some packages provided in the sample example and trying to create an endpoint using the below code
but with this code, I am getting

```
{"error": "unauthorized","error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"}`.
```

Any sample code for the complete authentication process/setting only for the JWT grant using requestJWTUserToken in the SpringBoot application?

```
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Envelope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(DocuSignServiceController.BASE_URI)
class DocuSignServiceController {

  static final String BASE_URI = "/docusign";

  DocuSignService docuSignService;

  public DocuSignServiceController(DocuSignService docuSignService) {
    this.docuSignService = docuSignService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/get-envelopes")
  public List<Envelope> getAllEnvelopes(
      @RequestParam(value = "email", defaultValue = "false") String email) throws ApiException, IOException {
    return docuSignService.getAllEnvelopes(email);
  }

  @GetMapping("/get-single-envelope")
  public Envelope getSingleEnvelopesById(
      @RequestParam(value = "envelopeId", defaultValue = "false") String envelopeId)
      throws ApiException {
    return docuSignService.getEnvelopeByID(envelopeId);
  }

  @GetMapping("/get-document-url")
  public String getDocumentUrl(
      @RequestParam(value = "envelopeId", defaultValue = "false") String envelopeId,
      @RequestParam(value = "email", defaultValue = "false") String email)
      throws ApiException {
    return docuSignService.getDocumentUrl(envelopeId, email);
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Can someone share a sample code "_ -- sorry, that's off-topic here.  Please read [ask]

Comment: I have changed to text. thank you

Comment: The call to requestJWTUserToken() is using the DocuSign.eSign maven package. It doesn't matter if it's springboot or anything. The issue here must be configuration and the data that you pass to this call. If you pass the same exact information to this call (triple check please) and it works in one and not another - you may need to open a support ticket

Comment: I have added Docusign.eSign maven package. I think you are right I am missing something related to configurations.

Answer (score 0):

To use JWT Grant you need the following:

1. An IK (Client ID) that you generate in the developer account.
2. You need an RSA Private key file, which you copy/paste for this IK exactly the way it was generated for you.
3. You need the userId of the user that will be impersonated and API calls made on their behalf. You can find this userId (GUID) in the Apps and Keys page of your developer account.
4. redirectURI set for the IK. This URI will be used in the consent (step 5 below) URL that you geneate.
5. You need to provide consent for this user by logging into the developer account with this user and building a URI that includes the IK (generated in #1) and the scopes **signature** and **impersonation**.

Once you ensure 1-5 are done correctly, you can call `requestJWTUserToken()` and should get a token without an error.

Note that all of this (1-5) can be done for you automatically if you use the [quickstart.](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/)